# Undefined method when calling method from initialize in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a class that inherits from another. When calling the constructor in the child it is making a call to the parent, which makes a call to a method. For me that should work perfectly fine but I get an exception. The ruby code looks like:

```
class MyTestClass
    def initialize
        @foo = "hello world"
        puts "init parent"
        writeFoo
    end

    def writeFoo
        puts @foo + " from base"
    end
end

class MySubClass < MyTestClass
    def initialize
        puts "init sub"
        super
    end

    def writeFoo
        puts @foo + " from sub"
        super.writeFoo
    end
end

@foo = MySubClass.new
```

When running that code I get an undefined method exception as below, but the right output is printed. Can someone please explain why?

```
/Users/tj/dev/coursera/sml/hw6/test.rb:21:in `writeFoo': undefined method `writeFoo' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/tj/dev/coursera/sml/hw6/test.rb:5:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tj/dev/coursera/sml/hw6/test.rb:16:in `initialize'
    from /Users/tj/dev/coursera/sml/hw6/test.rb:25:in `new'
    from /Users/tj/dev/coursera/sml/hw6/test.rb:25:in `<main>'
init sub
init parent
hello world from sub
hello world from base
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ruby `super` means calls superclass implementation of the current method - it is not, unlike some languages a mechanism for calling arbitrary methods from the base class.

```
super.writeFoo
```

Calls the superclass implantation of the current method (ie `writeFoo`) and then calls writeFoo on the result of that (hence the error).

Comment: I'm not sure that is the problem here. The `writeFoo` in the child class works fine. It's the call to `writeFoo` from `initialize` that is causing the problem and I can't see why. Everything outputs correctly but I don't understand the error message in this case.

Comment: It is causing the problem. You're calling nil.writeFoo (because that is what the call to super is returning). Change it to just 'super' and you should be ok.